# how SELECT people within age range

Tags: mysql, select, pdo

I've already tried all other questions/solutions, and no answer. so here it is: I need to `SELECT * FROM people WHERE` (dob is 18 to 40)

but my dob is stored as `DATE` type YYYY-MM-DD

need to select people between 18 and 40 for example!

Comment: So how do you compute somebody's age, if you have his date of birth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `BETWEEN` with some year calculation `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'1980-02-04',NOW())`

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`dob`,NOW()) BETWEEN  18 AND 40
```

<kbd>[**See fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64aeaa/1)</kbd>

[**TIMESTAMPDIFF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

[**YEAR(date)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Comment: +1 This is the simplest way, but you are not using the YEAR(date) function in there, why put that link there?

Comment: as long as it's mysql 5.0+ this will work.

Comment: @FilipeSilva i want the difference in years so if you see an example here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: @gillyspy yes taken example from mysql 5.5 manual

Comment: @dianuj FYI, since `now()` is timestamp (has a time component) one should avoid doing arithmetic of this type with `now()` but instead use `current_date`

Comment: @dianuj. Yes. the timestampdiff thing is why i upvoted. but your second link YEAR(date) is unrelated. that's a function to get the year from a date. You are not using that.

Comment: @FilipeSilva its only for showing how to get the year from date no use of it  at all but added as reference

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate 40 years ago from today, and 18 years ago from today. Let's say it was `1940-01-01` and `1980-01-01`, then it would be:

`WHERE dob BETWEEN '1940-01-01' AND '1980-01-01';`

Answer (score 0):

Since age is relative to today:

```
select * from people where 
date_sub(curdate(), interval 40 year)  =< dob
and date_sub(curdate(), interval 18 year) >= dob
```

This will work on any version of mysql

Answer (score 0):

since I do not know the SQL dialect you use I take the full variant

since `age` is now - birth (!)

```
select * from people where
    current date - date(birth) > MINAGE
    and
    current date - date(birth) < MAXAGE
```

`current date` depends on SQL you are using